# A script that copys horisontal data and paste it vertically on another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Im looking for a script that copys horisontal data (a form submisson) and paste it vertically on another sheet. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Why not use the native `=TRANSPOSE(Range)` function in a Sheet? If it's across sheets, you can nest it inside `IMPORTRANGE` and get the same effect. You don't need Apps Script.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both sheets are in the same spreadsheet and assuming that your first sheet is your source while the second one is the destination sheet, then you can do the following:

```
function myFunction() {

  var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // source spreadsheets
  var srcSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0];

  // get the data of row number 0
  var row = 0;
  var data = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // copy it to the columne
  var dstSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheets()[1];
  for ( i=0; i < data[row].length; i++) {
    dstSheet.getRange(i+1,1).setValue( data[row][i] );
  }
}
```